# Настройка Visual Studio 2017.Как отобразить методы классов в Обозревателе решений

Tags: visual-studio, ide, visual-studio-2017, обозреватель

Справа стандартный проект в той же студии, а слева мой. Где и что нажать, чтобы студия также отображала методы и свойства?
[image]

Comment: А как наоборот отключить это?)

Comment: Всё через тумблер. "Решения и папки" в контекстном меню где 8). Я сглупил.

Answer (score 1):

Это "фича" студии.
Переключать режимы можно по кнопке "Решения и папки" (на скриншоте кнопка чуть выше в "обозревателе")...